# Finding elapsed time in ms access query factoring in 8am to 5pm work day

Tags: ms-access, vba

Im using this function

```
Public Function ElapsedTime(Start As Date, Finish As Date) As String
    'Calculates elapsed time between 2 date/times and
    'parses it out into Hours-Minutes-Seconds in HH:MM:SS format
    
    Dim HoursLapsed, SecondsLeft, MinutesLapsed, SecondsLapsed, TotalSeconds As Long

    TotalSeconds = DateDiff("s", Start, Finish)
    HoursLapsed = Int(TotalSeconds / 3600)
    SecondsLeft = TotalSeconds Mod 3600
    MinutesLapsed = Int(SecondsLeft / 60)
    SecondsLapsed = SecondsLeft Mod 60

    ElapsedTime = Format(HoursLapsed, "00") & ":" & Format(MinutesLapsed, "00") & ":" & Format(SecondsLapsed, "00")
End Function
```

This is my query

```
SELECT
    ElapsedTime([Date_Faxed],[Date_Found]) AS Duration, 
    dbo_yard_request.Salesman, 
    dbo_yard_request.Make, 
    dbo_yard_request.Model, 
    dbo_yard_request.ID, 
    dbo_yard_request.Found2
FROM 
    dbo_yard_request
WHERE 
    (((dbo_yard_request.Found2)=True));
```

It works fine except i need to factor in the end of day at 5pm and start of new day at 8am.

For example

> DATE_FAXED = 1/22/2015 4:45:22 PM
>
> DATE_FOUND = 1/23/2015 8:55:13 AM

The elapsed time should be one hour and ten minutes, not 16 hours

Comment: Could you do something like `TotalDays * 15` which would give you the number of hours to subtract per each time period? (I am just thinking of a quick fix)

Comment: What happens if the dates are two days apart? Or if it falls on a weekend? Or outside work hours?